# Repeating an http.Request multiple times inside a reverse proxy

Tags: go

I'm implementing a [http.RoundTripper](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#RoundTripper) in Go, and as part of [httputil.ReverseProxy](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#ReverseProxy) implementation.

I need to buffer an incoming request, and repeat it several times, depending on the response I get from the backend. To do this, I use [request.Write](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.Write) and [http.ReadRequest](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ReadRequest). (I am actually not sure if this is a good idea, if there are any better ways, I'm interested.)

After deserializing request from `[]byte` with [http.ReadRequest](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ReadRequest) and repeat it using the http.DefaultTransport’s roundtripper, I get this printed in my stderr:

```
2019/08/01 14:35:51 http: proxy error: unsupported protocol scheme ""
```

So it looks like for some reason I need to set `req.URL` again after deserializing to make it work.

Here's roughly how my code looks like:

```golang
func (s *myServer) RoundTrip(origReq *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    var b bytes.Buffer
    if err := origReq.Write(&b); err != nil {
        return nil, errors.Wrap(err,"failed to buffer request")
    }
    for retries := 0; retries < s.maxRetries; retries++{
        req, err := http.ReadRequest(bufio.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(b.Bytes()))) // probably can be simplified
        if err != nil {
            return nil, errors.Wrap(err,"failed to un-buffer request")
        }
        req.URL = origReq.URL // <-- why is this necessary?

        resp, err := http.DefaultTransport.RoundTrip(req)
        if err != nil {
            return resp, err
        }
        if needRepeat(resp) {
            continue
        }
        return resp, nil
    }
}
```

Comment: ReadRequest reads a server request.  Request.Write writes a client request.  See the [Request.URL documentation](https://godoc.org/net/http#Request.URL) for how the Request.URL is handled differently in client and server requests.

Comment: Given that ReadRequest and Request.Write are not inverses of each other, it probably better to copy the request body before the loop and create a new request on each iteration using data from the original request and the copied request body.

Comment: Fee free to add this as an answer. I guess you’re right. For simple requests, body can be replaced and the rest can be reused.

Answer (score 1):

[ReadRequest](https://godoc.org/net/http#ReadRequest) 
reads a server request. [Request.Write](https://godoc.org/net/http#Request.Write) writes a client request. See the [Request.URL](https://godoc.org/net/http#Request.URL) documentation for how the Request.URL is handled differently in client and server requests.

Given that ReadRequest and Request.Write are not inverses of each other, 
a better approach is to copy the request body before the loop and create a new request on each iteration using data from the original request and the copied request body.